# Visual Studio 2012 Keyboard Freezing

Tags: visual-studio, razor, visual-studio-2012, resharper

I am having an issue within the razor view in Visual Studio 2012. For some reason, most of the time when I am trying to edit a style property, my keyboard freezes and doesn't allow me to type anything.

```
<section style="height: 15[Try to edit here]">
```

For instance, trying to add in a zero or 'px' where the "Try to edit here" has been placed above is impossible as the keyboard freezes.

I have ReSharper 7.1 installed, I'm not sure if that is the culprit?

Closing the tab and re-opening it fixes the issue, but it then re-occurs later on (not sure if there is a pattern as to when it re-occurs)

Comment: Does it stop other things like keyboard shortcuts from working?

Comment: Both Windows shortcuts, and VS shortcuts (Ctrl+Space for suggestions for instance) still work.

Comment: Try to disable ReSharper temporary via Tools | Options | ReSharper -> Suspend. If your problem won't manifest itself without ReSharper, then please take a snapshot (ReSharper | Help | Profile Visual Studio) and send it to us. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This happens to me often. I just switch tabs and come back and it doesn't happen(for sometime of course :-)). It could be some kind of unresolvable bug although i would suggest that you uninstall ReSharper and try again to see if it gets fixed.

Answer (score 0):

It happens to me and my other colleagues as well.

I have found it to be linked to having a floating code window(s). Unlike the floating window for something like Find Results (without a title bar), these appear almost like another instance of Visual Studio. These do not come to the front when the main Visual Studio Window is selected. I have found the keyboard stops responding only on these windows if there is a Find Results kind of floating window open. When the problem occurs, clicking on another VS window and come back sorts it.

In earlier versions of VS, any pulled code windows appeared without a thick title bar and window controls box.

I tried posting images of the two kinds of floating windows but don't have enough reputation to do so! Let me know if it is confusing and I'll try to clarify.

This may not be the only way for this problem to occur but this is what I've observed consistently in the last few weeks of using Visual Studio 2012. I have C# environment settings with Resharper 7 and Reflector installed.